# Service not binding when starting Activity when Phone is Locked

Tags: android, service, kotlin, android-wake-lock

I receive a push notification and I call an activity in onMessageReceived.

```
val i = Intent()
i.setClass(this, PreCallActivity::class.java!!)
i.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
val callRequest = CallParser.convertRemoteMessageToCallReq(remoteMessage)
i.putExtra(PreCallActivity.EXTRA_CALL_TYPE, "incoming")
i.putExtra(PetZamPubnubService.EXTRA_CALL_REQUEST, callRequest)
startActivity(i)
```

in the onCreate I set some flags and acquire a wakelock

```
this.window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD or
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD or
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_pre_call)

val pm = getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG_WAKE_LOCK)
wl?.acquire()
```

And I bind and start a service

```
val intent = Intent(this@PreCallActivity, MyPubnubService::class.java)
startService(intent)
bindService(intent, pubnubServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
```

The problem I am encountering is that when the app is coming from being Killed with the Phone LOCKED or Display is OFF, I am unable to access my service and gives me.

```
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
at com.myapp.myapp.push.PubnubServiceConn.publishMessage(PubnubServiceConn.kt:147)
at com.myapp.myapp.push.PubnubServiceConn.publishCallRejected(PubnubServiceConn.kt:80)
at com.myapp.myapp.videocall.PreCallActivity$enableInComingControls$2.onClick(PreCallActivity.kt:216)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My question is that is there a specific handling I should do to ensure that my services is started correctly coming from a LOCKED/OFF Phone and App is Killed?

I already tested the following scenarios and the app is working fine

1. App in Foreground
2. App in Background
3. App in Background AND Screen is Locked/OFF
4. App is KILLED AND Screen is turned ON

Comment: i think you should do call either startservice() or bindservice() not both.

Comment: @L7ColWinters Im currently using a `ServiceConnection` along with another `Service` to publish my Pubnub messages.

Comment: @JaydipKalkani let me check that. thank you

Comment: let me know it's working or not?

Comment: The behavior is still the same

Comment: on which mobile are you testing your app? on emulator or on real device? and which api it contains? and if real device then of which company?

Comment: Im using my personal nexus 5 on Android M.